# Pressing ESC button disables further use of that <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code for closing the popup using ESC Key. But after ESC button is pressed the link used to create pop up becomes disabled.

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       $(".overlay").hide();
    }   
    });
```

This is the HTML code

```
<a href="#popup1
 <li>bla bla</li>
</a>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
     <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you show() it again?

Comment: can you show us the code that opens the popup? if it's been hidden, it maybe needs to be shown again

Comment: That is where i'm confused @Martijn

Comment: have you used bootstrap popup or anything else

Comment: When i use the above code it gets hidden. Can i know how to show again? @Kaddath

Comment: Not bootstrap popup @Jinesh

Comment: You hide the overlay. That must mean you show it somwhere too.

Comment: It looks like there is a pre-existing logic somewhere on your page (that you have not posted in your question) that disables the trigger button when it is clicked on. That's why we always strongly encourage posted a **minimal, concrete and verifiable example** because you are sure you can reproduce your issue in a code snippet before asking.

Comment: ya i have used above html @Kaddath

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       $(".overlay").hide();
    }   
});
$("your-a-tag-id-or-class").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".overlay").show();  
});
```

Comment: I think in pop up overlay default display block

Comment: ya its block @Jinesh